# Microsoft Graph Send Mail giving ErrorSubmissionQuotaExceeded

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph API to send mails to users of a domain in which I am an admin. I have created a script for doing so. I am able to send some mails (around 10000) after which it returns an error

"ErrorSubmissionQuotaExceeded" and says please try after some time.

Is their a specific time after which I should try again ?

Is their a way to increase the quota (or by passing some parameter with the graph request so that it may delete the previous mails and refresh the quota) ?

Answer (score 3):

Transport within exchange limits the number of emails that a given account can send per minute.  The default settings in O365 are 30 messages per minute.  Try it again by limit your submission rate to 1 mail every 2 seconds.  I'm not sure how it is calculated off the top of my head (per minute, per hour, per whatever), but start there and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I am already making the request after 2 seconds (by making the Thread sleep for 2 seconds after every request), but still facing the same issue.

Comment: I just chatted with the transport team: We have 2 throttles (rejecting msg at submission time) that can cause this.

1. Recipient rate Limit –
10K recipients (P1 & P2) /24 hours. That is, pre-expansion. (So a DL counts as 1.)

2. Msg Rate Limit. We also have the 20 msg/minute rate limit.